# How to access css file in laravel 8?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have been trying to access it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="red">
        @yield('content')
    </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

I put the background red in the css file but nothing is changing. Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you have to have your assets in the `public` folder if you want to serve them ... that should be the only accessible folder for the website and where the web server serves the files from

Comment: put it in `public/css`

Comment: Did you compile the assets? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#introduction

Comment: Thanks everyone I got it solved by putting it in the public folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it in public/css and use it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: with assets path or whiteout but don't forgot about '/' before the path it`s important   /css/app.css

Answer (score 2):

You need to install *laravel mix*. As it is added in the *package.json* in fresh installation of laravel, follow below steps:

1. run `npm install` to install package that are added in *package.json* [more](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#installing-laravel-mix)
2. add `mix.css('resource/css/app.css', 'css');` to the **webpack.mix.js** file [more](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/css#general-css-compilation)
3. run `npm run dev` to compile files that are addressed in *webpack.mix.js* [more](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#running-mix)
4. link to your *app.css* as `{{ asset('css/app.css') }}` in the desired blade file.

**Notice**: You need to run `npm run dev` after any changes that you make in the *resource/css/app.css* file. Or benefit from `npm run watch` which complies automatically after any changes.

**Notice**: Press `ctrl+f5` to clear cache after every change or use [cache busting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)

Answer (score 0):

clear your browser cache, and make sure that directory of CSS file was public/css